# How many people can play ORION: Prelude (aka Dino Hunt) in online coop mode?

Tags: orion-prelude, orion-dino-hunt

I have scoured the internets looking for the answer to this question.  The game looks like a fun concept simple shooter, so I was wondering how many people can play in an online coop mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The player limit for coop is 5. If you want to play with more people than that, there are a few versus modes available which support 5v5 (10 players total).

Answer (score 1):

So far I'm aware the max amount of players is 5.